# Sharepoint 2010 Search Results returns empty rating

Tags: 2010, search, search-results, pages, rating

I have document library named Pages where all my pages are there. Every page of this library has rating control. The rating Column of the library shows stars for pages which confirms that the ratings are being saved.

Currently i am implementing search functionality for the site and want to display page rating in the search results.

I created the Managed properties for both crawled properties(OWS_averageRating and OWS_RatingCounter) and added managed properties in fetched properties of Search Core Results WebPart.

But, in the results the rating and rating Count tags are empty.

Here is the xml, which i get from Search Core Results Web Part:

```
<All_Results>
    <Result>
      <id>1</id>
      <workid>3490</workid>
      <rank>78000306</rank>
      <title>Test</title>
      <author_multival>System Account</author_multival>
      <author>System Account</author>
      <size>178578</size>
      <url>http://Server/Pages/Test.aspx</url>
      <urlEncoded>http%3A%2F%2Fserver%2FPages%2FTest%2Easpx</urlEncoded>
      <description></description>
      <write>26/11/2012</write>
      <sitename>http://server/Pages</sitename>
      <collapsingstatus>0</collapsingstatus>
      <hithighlightedsummary>summary </hithighlightedsummary>
      <hithighlightedproperties>
        <HHTitle>test</HHTitle>
        <HHUrl>http://server/Pages/<c0>Test.aspx</c0></HHUrl>
      </hithighlightedproperties>
      <contentclass>STS_ListItem_850</contentclass>
      <isdocument>True</isdocument>
      <picturethumbnailurl></picturethumbnailurl>
      <serverredirectedurl></serverredirectedurl>
      <rating></rating>
      <ratingcount></ratingcount>
      <fileextension>ASPX</fileextension>
      <ows_metadatafacetinfo></ows_metadatafacetinfo>
      <popularsocialtags />
      <imageurl imageurldescription="Web Page">/_layouts/images/html16.png</imageurl>
    </Result>
    <TotalResults>1</TotalResults>
    <NumberOfResults>1</NumberOfResults>
  </All_Results>
```

Am i missing something.
I have used these links to get ratings in search :

http://todd-carter.com/post/2010/10/05/pimp-document-ratings-within-sharepoint-search-results/

http://blogs.technet.com/b/speschka/archive/2009/10/28/using-the-new-sharepoint-2010-ratings-feature-in-search.aspx

Could someone help me with this please....

Regards

Mohit Leekha

Comment: After adding the two managed properties you need to make a full crawl. have you done it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure you perform a Full Crawl after creating the Managed Properties to populate them with data. Incremental crawl will not be enough.

Comment: Thanks, Worked like a charm....Problem was I used Start all Crawles instead of Full Crawl.

Comment: I've done the same mistake myself, too many times!

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked whether the appropriate timer jobs have been properly executing??

- User Profile Service Application - **Social Data Maintenance Job**  -
  Aggregates social tags and ratings and cleans the social data change
  log.
- User Profile Service Application - **Social Rating Synchorization Job** -
  Synchronizes rating values between the social database and content
  database.

Comment: Both are Scheduled on Hourly Basis.

Comment: Tried running them manually?